# Is there a way to add number values from one column based on the value in other column in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have 2 columns that I need to use to create a measure that shows how many incidents (volume) are of the particular error types in DAX.

| Error type | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 50 |
| 400 | 75 |
| 500 | 125 |

Is there a way to do it with IF statement ?

I believe that I need something like this :

if value in column 'error type' is >= 200 and <500 then sum...

Comment: Add your expected results for that dataset, and clarify whether you are looking for a `Calculated Column` or a `Measure`.

Comment: The expected result is to have a volume of incidents by each error type. I also have a product and date columns by which I would like to see how the volume of incidents changes, so I am not sore if I need a measure or a new column.

Comment: Do some research on Calculated Columns vs Measures and come back when you've decided which one you require.

Comment: sorry, it needs to be a calculated column

Comment: So each entry appears multiple times in the Error type column?

Comment: Yes, there are approximately 15 different error types (401,402,403,500, 505, etc.) and each appears multiple times as there are 2 more column (date, product id)

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Column:

```
=
VAR ThisErrorType = Table1[Error type]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[Volume] ),
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[Error type] = ThisErrorType
        )
    )
```